# Best practices for mass file transfer with verification?

Tags: linux, windows, bacula, data-integrity, verification

I'm looking for a bit of advice on transferring a several files from Windows-based workstations to a Linux Server running Ubuntu Server LTS 10.04.  At the moment I've been mounting the shares on the Linux box and rsyncing them, but I'm not sure if this is validating the data that's being sent.  Someone suggested that I used Bacula for backups, which I plan to do to take advantage of VSS for 100% data integrity, but for the initial transfer it doesn't seemm that Bacula is an option.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to verify integrity of a remote file transfer](http://serverfault.com/questions/98597/how-to-verify-integrity-of-a-remote-file-transfer)

Comment: None of the proposed solutions thus far take advantage of VSS.  I don't want to have to transfer files THEN run an md5 checksum, that's unnecessary overhead.  There must be a more efficient method.

Comment: What are you talking about?  Bacula can do a full backup.  Why do you think you need to do some form of initial backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5 sums of the files on server one, compared to MD5 sums on server two post-transfer.

Comment: What MD5 sum utility would be the best?  I seem to have issued with MD5Summer as the output doesn't match the output from the md5sum package resident on Linux installs.

Comment: MD5 checksums use the same algorithm. If they don't match, either the file has changed or something has corrupted it.